# How to show an angle axis in a RevolutionPlot3D plot

Tags: plotting

I want to make a `RevolutionPlot3D` of a three dimensional wave-function which is defined only between two radius. I work in cylindrical coordinates. The idea is to get a plot of the whole region for a given height in the cylinder.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[ψ3DNorm[1, r, ϕ, 2], {r, 1, 2}, {ϕ, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

I want to be able to keep a track of the angle on the plot by having an axis giving the angle around the plot or at least, a axis stating the angle 0. How can I do that?

Comment: You could try `Show[
 RevolutionPlot3D[
  Cos[4t], {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 \[Pi]}
  , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}
  , Boxed -> False
  ]
 , Graphics3D[{
   Thick, Red,
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 2, 0}}]
   }]
 ]`. You can obviously add more complex graphics this way as well.

Comment: Thank you but with that solution, you don't have a clue about the direction of rotation in which the angle is plotted by the function?

Comment: Why not use something like `Hue[]` to color your surface according to the angle of interest instead?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could color-code some custom mesh lines to indicate the angular values at that position:

```
plot = RevolutionPlot3D[
   Cos[4 t], {r, 1, 2}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
   Mesh -> {{
            {1*^-6, Directive[Black, Thick]}, 
            {Pi/2, Directive[Red, Thick]}, 
            {Pi, Directive[Darker@Green, Thick]}, 
            {3/2 Pi, Directive[Blue, Thick]}}
           },
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z, t, theta, r}, theta]},
   ImageSize -> Large
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The black line corresponds to $\theta = 0$, the red line to $\theta = \pi/2$, and so on.

(Note that I had to shift the first mesh line slightly away from $0$ because otherwise it would have been overshadowed by a thing gray line at that  position, whose origin is unclear to me.)

Comment: I would guess that the gray line you got came from `BoundaryStyle`. Try setting it to `None`.

Comment: @J.M. I should have been more clear. I had in fact tried to set `BoundaryStyle -> None`, which indeed removes the grey "mesh line" at $0$ as well as the boundary line, but even then no custom mesh line is shown at the $0$ position: [code&result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bhuQp.png). I have also tried machine-precision `0.` instead, with no luck. I'll dig into older questions later today; perhaps this is a known issue?

Comment: Hmm, I think that would be due to roundoff error, so that the $\theta$ mesh doesn't actually start at $0$. I believe this problem has indeed been encountered before here, but I can't find relevant threads at the moment.